# Set Sass Variable value from web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sass

Based on the Custom Publish Profile (Be it as a Release/Stage or any custom client based release mode), I want to set a Sass variable's value. i.e. Read the Sass Variable's value from web.config file which can be further used to decide which style sheets to be used a that particular environment. I have also googled the queries but didn't find any relevant answers. Not sure whether it is possible.
If Yes, then how? If No, then is there any alternate way to do it?

Please Help!

Thanks!